# Semistable sheaves on rationally connected manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $(X,H)$ be a polarized projective manifold of dimension $n$ defined over $\mathbb C$, and let $\mathcal E$ be a reflexive sheaf on $X$.

If for every subsheaf $\mathcal F \subset \mathcal E$ the following inequality holds
$$
\frac{c_1(\mathcal F)\cdot H^{n-1}}{\mathrm{rank}(\mathcal F)} \le \frac{c_1(\mathcal E)\cdot H^{n-1}}{\mathrm{rank}(\mathcal E)}
$$
then we say that $\mathcal E$ is semistable.

Mehta-Ramanathan proved that if $\mathcal E$ is semi-stable then its restriction to a sufficiently general curve $C$ cut out by elements of $|mH|$, $m \gg 0$, is also semistable.

> **Question.** If we further assume that $X$ is rationally connected can
>   we ensure the existence  of a very free
>   morphism $i: \mathbb P^1 \to X$  such
>   that $i^*\mathcal E$ is semistable?

Recall that $i: \mathbb P^1 \to X$ is a very free morphism  if and only if $i^* TX$ is ample.

---

As observed by mdeland in the comments, $i^* \mathcal E$ is semistable if and only if 
$$i^* \mathcal E \simeq \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(k)^{\oplus \mathrm{rank}(\mathcal E)}   .$$
In particular $\deg(i^* \mathcal E)$ is divisible by $\mathrm{rank}(\mathcal E)$.

If we start with an arbitrary  very free morphism $i: \mathbb P^1 \to X$ we can compose it with a rational map $\varphi : \mathbb P^1 \to \mathbb P^1$ of degree $m \cdot \mathrm{rank}(\mathcal E), m \in \mathbb N$, to obtain a new morphism $i' = i \circ \varphi$. The original question seems to be related to the problem.

> **Problem.** Describe the splitting type of a general  deformation of $i'
> > : \mathbb P^1 \to X$ for $m \gg 0$.

Any ideas/references on how to tackle this kind of problem ?

Comment: i^*E is semistable on P^1 iff it splits into a direct sum of OO(a) (all of the same degree).  In particular, you would have to have that deg(i)*deg(E) was divisible by rank(E).  As far as I know, we don't have too many techniques to arrange this "balanced" splitting condition.  Even if X is rat conn we don't know how to show the existence of a rat curve so that i^TX is semistable.

Comment: While I can't offer much insight into a proof, I am very interested in this question.  I have a recent preprint where I (roughly) show general rank r semistable Steiner bundles on P^n pull back to balanced bundles on general degree r rational curves.  I'm afraid the proof is strongly based on the special form of these bundles, however.

Comment: That is nice, Jack!  I think it goes to show that even is X = PP^n and even if you make strong assumptions about the minimal resolution of E, it could/will still be difficult to prove that E pulls back to a semistable bundle on some rational curve.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the question seems difficult.  Although, in my work proving that the pullbacks are balanced also gives the first proof that those bundles are semistable--potentially one could infer the balanced splitting result more easily if semistability was already known.